# How to avoid calling onDestroy when do not keep activities checked

Tags: android

When do not keep activities is checked under developer option of android device then after on pause onDestroy called for that reason I am unable to get resume my activity. Is there any solution to ignore do not keep activities is checked or unchecked to avoid calling onDestroy. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: then is it possible to uncheck do not keep activities from developer option through code?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. If your app doesn't restore properly after being destroyed you just need to fix it. Save your state in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore in `onCreate()`; move any data loading out of the activity; etc.

Without seeing code, all I can say is read up more on the `Activity` lifecycle and make sure you're handling it properly. If you are, then it shouldn't matter whether or not this option is selected -- your app should behave the same way.

Comment: then is it possible to uncheck do not keep activities from developer option through code?

Comment: That is also not possible.

Comment: actually i m developing video conferencing app if "do not keep activities" checked for that situation activity destroy whenever goes to onPause i need help to restrict to destroy activity.